# Enabling Template Path Hints for Storefront for Magento 2 has no Effect

Tags: magento2

I have enabled the templates hint for developer troubleshooting, but the hints not shown at frontend, do you know any reasons?

[image]

Comment: i saw some posts reporting the same issue but no solution, could anyone share your idea?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes Path Hints won't be shown if:

- The URL does not contain the `templatehints` parameter.
- Developer Client Restrictions has an IP addressed listed that isn't yours.
- The cache was not flushed after changing the option.
- The site was changed to Production mode.

Developer Client Restrictions can be check in `Stores -> Settings -> Configuration` then `Advanced -> Developer -> Developer Client Restrictions`. Check that the `Allowed IPs` field is either blank, or contains your IP address.

Comment: Thanks, point #2 has flushed, #3 is developer mode, but #1 is interesting, i don't know this. what is developer client restriction, how can i find this out?

Comment: @DennisChan I've added the information to the Answer.

Comment: @DennisChan just to be sure - did you add the value to the url to see the hints?

Comment: yeah, finally find out the url requires a templatehints=xxxxx parameter to show the hints. many thanks.

Comment: @DennisChan It never occurred to me that perhaps the URL param was not included. I've amended the Answer with your tip. Thank **you**.

Answer (score 0):

You can use these commands to enable/disable template path hints.

```
bin/magento dev:template-hints:enable
bin/magento dev:template-hints:disable
```

Flush the cache after enabling using `bin/magento c:f`

Comment: no, not working.

Answer (score 0):

Sometime removing var files manually may also helps,

```
rm -rf generated/code/ generated/metadata/ var/cache/ var/view_preprocessed/ var/page_cache/
```

### Update

And as per given snapshot of config, you have to add query string `templatehints=magento` at the end in URL like this

```
http://yourdomain.com/?templatehints=magento
```

If you don't want to use this kind of query string and want to show template hints on each request, please change `Enable Hints for Storefront with URL Parameter` to `No`

(don't forget to flush cache and run above `rm` command after this config change)

Comment: no, not working also.

Comment: See updated answer, that will might help you

Comment: yes, you're right. after add templatehints=magento to the url, the hints display. i never know this meaning, i learn it now. thanks.

Comment: Happy to hear that
An up-vote and accepting answer will be appreciated if it is resolved by this answer.